# Rounding Time with NodaTime

Tags: c#, time, rounding, nodatime

I have some `LocalDateTime`s where I need to round the time of day up/down to the nearest minute number according to a list of defined minutes.
For instance, if I have the datetime `2018-03-20T12:13:47` and I have to round it to the next half hour (so minutes are either 00 or 30), I would get `2018-03-20T12:30:00`. Rounding down would give `2018-03-20T12:00:00`.

The rounding could be to any arbitrary minute, e.g. every 10 minutes (0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50), every quarter hour (0, 15, 30, 45), or say to a quarter to or after (15, 45). This means the rounded date could end up on another date.

Is there any functionality in NodaTime that could help with this rounding, or do I have to write it myself? I have a working version now, but it includes double loops and adding hours and minutes to a midnight.

Answer (score 6):

There's a *sort* of functionality that will help: the idea of "adjusters". If you write your own method that returns a `Func<LocalTime, LocalTime>` you can apply that to `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` and `OffsetTime` (in 2.3+) using the `With` method.

That will help with the truncate case pretty easily:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var truncator = CreateTruncator(10);
        var start = new LocalDateTime(2018, 3, 21, 7, 32, 15);
        var truncated = start.With(truncator);
        Console.WriteLine(truncated); // 2018-03-21T07:30:00
    }

    static Func<LocalTime, LocalTime> CreateTruncator(int minuteGranularity) =>
        input => new LocalTime(
            input.Hour,
            input.Minute / minuteGranularity * minuteGranularity);
}
```

(Note that if you give that a `minuteGranularity` of 7 or something else that's not a factor of 60, it will still truncate to periods that always start on the hour.)

However, there's no way of that advancing the date. The adjuster mechanism works for a `Func<LocalDateTime, LocalDateTime>` as well - you can apply that to `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`. But yes, you'd need to write the code to do that adjustment yourself. As you say, there are lots of different options you *might* want for rounding, and it's hard for Noda Time to cover all the possible use cases.

I'd definitely recommend writing a method to create an adjuster rather than just writing a method accepting a `LocalDateTime` and a number of minutes - it provides a way of you passing the adjuster around very easily, and as I've shown, it fits in with Noda Time's own adjustments. (Look in the [`TimeAdjusters`](https://nodatime.org/unstable/api/NodaTime.TimeAdjusters.html) and [`DateAdjusters`](https://nodatime.org/unstable/api/NodaTime.DateAdjusters.html) classes for the ones we provide out of the box.)

If you need help writing a specific adjuster, that's probably worth asking in a separate question. I wouldn't *expect* it to need double loops etc.